# Rewriting the root URL for pretty URLs

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm writing an htaccess file to rewrite my  URLs into a prettier format so that;

- **index.php?page=1** becomes **/home**
- **about.php?page=2** becomes **/about**

You get the idea...

**Those I kind of have figured out and working, using the code below;**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?home/$ index.php?page=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?home$ index.php?page=1 [L]
```

But I want to rewrite the root URL so that `domain.com/` will go straight to `domain.com/home` as obviously on entry to the site the page variable will not have been passed through and this is what pulls in the appropriate content.

**My current htaccess code for that (which isn't working) is below;**

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$/ index.php?page=1 [L]
```

UPDATE
This current code that I have:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?home/$ index.php?page=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?home$ index.php?page=1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^$/ index.php?page=1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?about/$ index.php?page=2 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?about$ about.php?page=2 [L]

Redirect 301 ^/?$ /home
```

I can't use the code provided in first answer here because I have an issue when trying to pass two variables in to the rewrite - for example some of pages have urls like `product.php?page=6&prodId=21`.

Comment: Use a redirect rule to send `/` to `/home`. You also have 2 `home` rules. This `^$/` doesnt make sense, `$` is the end of the string.

Comment: @chris85 Thanks Chris. A redirect is just returning a server error. The duplicate rules are to deal with localhost.com/home and localhost.com/home/.

Comment: Make the trailing slash optional, like you did for the leading. What is the server error? What is the rule you wrote?

Comment: @chris85 I will do that. It was an object not found error - but now I'm getting an incorrect redirect and no matter what changes I make to htaccess file the redirect doesn't changed. The rule I wrote is `Redirect 301 / /home` my url is localhost/es-html/ and is now redirecting to localhost/homees-html/ but I can't stop it even when updating the htaccess

Comment: You need to be more specific then that, everything will match that and you'll probably go into a loop. Try `^/?$`.

Comment: @chris85 That works but isn't pulling in the vraiable so I get no page content and an undefined index error in PHP.

Comment: What variable, `$_GET['page']`?

Comment: @chris85 yes - this sets index.php?page=1 which i have rewritten to home and about.php?page=2 which i have rewritten to about etc

Comment: Can you update the question to what you currently have?

Comment: @chris85 sure thing, updated above.

Comment: Rather than updating your question to `I can't use the code provided in first answer` you should comment on that answer.  Your question mentions nothing about `product.php`.

Comment: @chris85 I'm trying to get that working but wanted to respond to you as promptly as possible hence why I'm not using it.

Comment: Your kinda splitting the question. If the answer below resolves the issue you should accept it. If you then have additional issues you should post a second question.

Comment: @chris85 ok, I'll get the redirect issue sorted and then start another question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this, see if it is working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^$ index.php?page=1 [NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(home|home/)$ index.php?page=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^(about|about/)$ about.php?page=2 [NC]
```

Comment: `(home|home/)` is unnecessary, and if the base rule isn't on wont account for leading slashes. `^/?home/?$` would do it.

Comment: @Abhishek that works when I add in my redirect but the page=x variable isn't being included when the root redirects to home.